# \emph vs. \mkbibemph and other things

Tags: biblatex, csquotes, emphasis

I usually use the commands that come with biblatex (like `mkbibemph`, `mkbibquote` etc.) *only* in my bibliography.

What about using them in the text of my document? Should I do that? Are there any advantages?For example, I remember reading something about that the biblatex-commands can rule whether or not the dot is inside or outside the quotation marks. But I don't know whether this is still the case, whether it works and if it is recommended.

So, what about `\emph` vs. `\mkbibemph`? Or `\mkbibquote` vs. `"..."` vs. `\enquote` (of csquotes)?

(I think these are the two commands I am most interested in, but I am sure that there are others that also come with `biblatex`, isn't that so (e.g. `\mkbibparens`)? What about those?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

adding

```
\show\mkbibemph
\show\mkbibquote
```

produces

```
> \mkbibemph=\protected macro:
->\emph .
l.6 \show\mkbibemph


? 
> \mkbibquote=\protected macro:
->\enquote .
l.10 \show\mkbibquote
```

so the biblatex ones are defined to expand to the normal ones by default.

Comment: The purpose of having different names is that they *can* be redefined when working on the bibliography.

Comment: @egreg yes that's what I meant by "by default" either way it means there is no harm using them in the main document if you wish I think?

Comment: I'd prefer using the "normal" names.

Comment: However, `\mkbibquote` does interact with the punctuation tracker, depending on the language...