# csquotes and invalid nesting with two nested \mkbibquotes

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, nesting, csquotes

I was surprised when today I got the error message `Package csquotes Error: Unbalanced groups or invalid nesting`. After a while I found the culprit in my bibliography-file. It is a bib-item whose title contains two nested `\mkbibquote`-commands like

```
Title = {aaa aaa \mkbibquote{bbb bbb \mkbibquote{ccc ccc} bbb bbb} aaa aaa}
```

I have to say, I was rather surprised that this caused any problem at all, in particulalr since David has demonstrated to me [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76317/12277) that the biblatex commands "are defined to expand to the normal ones by default". By "normal ones" he meant commands such as `\enquote` and it surely is alright to write `aaa aaa \enquote{bbb bbb \enquote{ccc ccc} bbb bbb} aaa aaa`, or isn't it?

So what's wrong with my bib-item?

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}    
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose,abbreviate=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
    Author = {Author},
    Journaltitle = {Journaltitle},
    Title = {aaa aaa \mkbibquote{bbb bbb \mkbibquote{ccc ccc} bbb bbb} aaa aaa},
    Year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{example}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking in the `log` file you will see:

> Level 3 quote invalid at this point. The maximum level is 2.

caused by the title being inside a `bibmkquote=enquote` already.  Just change the maximum level allowed by passing the `maxlevel` opiton to `csquotes`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}    
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose,abbreviate=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
    Author = {Author},
    Journaltitle = {Journaltitle},
    Title = {aaa aaa \mkbibquote{bbb bbb \mkbibquote{ccc ccc} bbb bbb} aaa aaa},
    Year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{example}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know! Any ideas as to why there is a default `maxlevel=2` at all? Shouldn't that be up to the sanity of the author?

Comment: I guess it is `2` as there are only two distinct pair of symbols, so the author should make a conscious decision to use deeper nesting.  The author should also be thinking of the sanity of the reader.